# Last date someone tried to logon

Tags: active-directory

I would like to find all Windows machines on a domain which have an issue preventing users to logon (e.g. broken network cable, broken display, broken hard drive, et cetera).

In Active Directory, there is `lastLogon` and `lastLogonTimestamp` from which I can tell at least that Windows did a successful startup and talked to the Domain Controller. But couldn't find anything which is related to a successful logon (which could still be prevented by a broken display or a broken keyboard).

Am I missing something or is this just not possible with a default Active Directory?

Comment: Active Directory would not have that kind of information unless you fed it that data using other tools.

Comment: Thank you. Feel free to add this as answer, so I could mark this as correct answer :)